# Generate sfdxAuthUrl from CumulusCI

Tags: salesforcedx, cumulusci

I'm looking into a way of handle automatic access token refresh for a scratch org and `sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store` looks like a good candidate. This command requires a `sfdxAuthUrl`.

When I `sfdx auth:web:login` into my scratch org I obtain the `sfdxAuthUrl` with `sfdx force:org:display -u something@example.com --verbose --json`.

Yet, when I do the same command from a newly created scratch org (just after `cci flow run`) the json's output has no `sfdxAuthUrl`. There is a way to obtain it from cci without having to first authenticate with the browser?

Or there is a better way to solve my original problem (access token refresh without browser and human intervention)?

Comment: Can you say more about your use case? Are you trying to persist access to a scratch org in some context other than where it is created?

Comment: @DavidReed yes, we need to access the scratch org from various services deployed in kubernetes (for QA). We store the access token in a kubernetes secret, but since  the access token usually expires after 24h, causing a lot of troubles in QA, I'm trying to find a way to refresh this token automatically from within kubernetes.

Comment: I'm suspecting the issue is that `sfdxAuthUrl` is not available when the devhub is authenticated with the jwt flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `sfdxAuthUrl` works only if you authenticate with `force:auth:web:login`.

Reference: [How to login to a ScratchOrg that was created by CI/CD scripts?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321686/how-to-login-to-a-scratchorg-that-was-created-by-ci-cd-scripts/321689#321689)